# Comparing to get seconds difference between java and mysql datetime

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I read a mysql date time field into one string e.g.

```
String arriveTime = rs1.getString("arriveTime");
```

Next step I try to get the current date and time using java to be similar format like the one I got from mysql.

```
DateFormat outDf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String currentDateTimer=null;
                    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                    currentDateTimer=outDf.format(date);
```

How can I minus the currentDateTime and arriveTime to get the net results in seconds. I would prefer to do it purely via java

Comment: `select unix_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(yourfield)`

Comment: What you mean by _get the net results in seconds_ ? give an example of what you want:)

Comment: Can you add the format for `arriveTime`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would not read a MySQL date-time into a `String`. I would change this,

```
String arriveTime = rs1.getString("arriveTime");
```

to

```
 java.sql.Date arriveTime = rs1.getDate("arriveTime");
```

Then you can use basic subtraction to get the result in milliseconds, then divide by a thousand to get that in seconds - so

```
long diff = new java.util.Date().getTime() - arriveTime.getTime();
System.out.println(diff / 1000);
```

Comment: @user3953386 Not with the approach here. Nor do you need a Calendar. Although you could always do it with a Calendar (or Joda Time).

Comment: I think I will follow your method is better simpler.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`I read a mysql date time field into one string`

If the column is varchar type it is ok you can read it using `resultsetObject.getString()`

But if your column type is Date then is it always recommended to get the value using `resultset.getDate()`

Mysql stores date in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
I try to get the current date and time using java to be similar format 
like the one I got from mysql.
```

When you do `resultset.getDate()` it will give you the java.sql.Date in format `yyyy-MM-dd`